# How to run all the webtests from commandline

Tags: c#, testing, dll, command-line, webtest

I have dll file for webtests. I used the below command to execute all my webtests

> mstest /testcontainer:"MyPath\PostAccessToken.dll"
>   /resultsfile:MyResultPath\MyResults.trx

When i tried the above command I got the below message.

> Microsoft (R) Test Execution Command Line Tool Version 12.0.21005.1
>   Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
>
> Loading PostAccessToken.dll... 
>   Starting execution...  No tests to execute.

My dll file contents are

```
[assembly: TargetFramework(".NETFramework,Version=v4.5", FrameworkDisplayName=".NET Framework 4.5")]
[assembly: AssemblyTitle("PostAccessToken")]
[assembly: AssemblyDescription("")]
[assembly: AssemblyConfiguration("")]
[assembly: AssemblyCompany("")]
[assembly: AssemblyProduct("PostAccessToken")]
[assembly: AssemblyCopyright("Copyright \x00a9  2016")]
[assembly: AssemblyTrademark("")]
[assembly: ComVisible(false)]
[assembly: Guid("2227ff72-2254-4e3e-af43-76a98b558c80")]
[assembly: AssemblyFileVersion("1.0.0.0")]
[assembly: Debuggable(DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.DisableOptimizations | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.EnableEditAndContinue | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.IgnoreSymbolStoreSequencePoints | DebuggableAttribute.DebuggingModes.Default)]
[assembly: CompilationRelaxations(8)]
[assembly: RuntimeCompatibility(WrapNonExceptionThrows=true)]
```

how can I run all webtests from this library by one command?

Comment: Why must you run them from the command line?

Comment: There are no option to run multiple webtest on VS2013 ultimate. executing thru command-line is the only option

Comment: You could run them by adding a console project to your solution and use that as your front-end.  You wouldn't need the command line then.

Comment: Even I add a console project to the solution, how to make webtest to run over Console project application?

Comment: Well, aren't your tests in a 'class'?  You can simply instantiate the class in the 'Main' method of your console app.

Comment: There won't be any specific class or Main method in tests. It will be a simple test which is created in the VS itself.